# Posting to WP via URL

Tags: posts, hooks, urls

Does anyone know of any solution to replicate the share to [facebook, twitter, etc], but with WordPress? With these social media options, you can share the post by just passing a URL with the parameters necessary. I also understand that you have to be logged in for these options to work, so we are aware that you may need to be logged into your wp site for this to work. Ideally, through a webhook that can be passed through a URL, but I can't think of anything that works like this.

Background about what I'm trying to do: I'm working with a company that creates NFT's out of media files and they want a share to WP button similar to the share to FB or Twitter. And they want to make it frictionless for WP users.

Comment: I'm unclear on how the proposed button functions. If I'm understanding you correctly, you're saying that on some site, a button can be placed and associated with a piece of content that, when clicked, will add that content as a new post to the user's own self-hosted WordPress installation? Or maybe wordpress.com site? Are you thinking this would require a corresponding plugin on their site? The former seems particularly tricky as I can't imagine a way to ascertain the URL of a visitor's self-hosted installation, short of asking them to enter it.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  Using the WP API to post to the site.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/232663/60844